# Do I need to escape/sanitize the following? If so, what is the best method?

Tags: php, sanitize

Do I need to escape/sanitize the following?

1. `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in a
   PHP script (not inserted into
   database or displayed to user), for
   example:

   ```
   if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']==$xyz) {
           echo "Congrats, you are using XYZ browser";
   } else {
           echo "You are not using XYZ browser.";
   }
   ```
2. `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` when
   placed as a session variable, for
   example:

   ```
   $_SESSION['userAgent']=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
   ```
3. Anything that is going to be hashed,
   for example:

   ```
   hash('sha512',$randomDataPostedByUser)
   ```
4. User input destined for email body
   (in other words, I've already taken
   care of email header injections).

If any of the above do need to be excaped/sanitized, what is the best method for each case?

Comment: You are probably missing a second `=` in your first example.

Comment: email body sounds fishy, all other examples look sane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no need for sanitation in any of the examples you show, with the following very rare exception for the mail body example:

> (Windows only) When PHP is talking to a SMTP server directly, if a full stop is found on the start of a line, it is removed. To counter-act this, replace these occurrences with a double dot.

However, you may need to sanitize the session variable later, depending on what you are going to do with it.

Other notes:

- Your first example doesn't seem to make sense, because user agent strings vary heavily. You will have to use `strstr()` or regular expressions to match user agents.
- Storing the user agent in a session variable might not be a good idea if you're  doing comparisons - just pull it from the $_SERVER array when you need it.

Comment: So it's not possible to create an exploit similar to the following situation? (I apologize in advance if this is absurd; I'm still learning.) `hash('sha512',$randomDataPostedByUser)` where `$randomDataPostedByUser` is `$unimportant)'moreCodeToRunAnExploit`

Comment: @user nope, because the `)'` will be interpreted as string data. There is no way to "break out" this way (except if running code using `eval()`, which one shouldn't do for this exact reason, among others)

Comment: @Pekka Excellent! Thanks! I realize the first one doesn't make a lot of sense, but I just couldn't come up with a better example off the top of my head. In terms of storing the user agent in the session variable, I was thinking that then I could see if it changed from request to request. From what I understand, unless it was being manipulated by the user, there shouldn't be a reason for it to change mid-session. By storing it in the session, I could track changes. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user yup, that makes sense - it's the best way to go about it.